# Download Files from RSS feeds using PHP (or BASH / Perl)

Tags: parsing, rss

I am in need of a script that will allow me to download files from an RSS feed, the files are all .wmv and I was wondering if there's a script in PHP, BASH or even Perl that can download the feed links?

Answer (score 0):

Use a class from any of these languages to parse RSS information. ([Magpie](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) is a popular one for PHP.) With that, you can obtain a URL you can download directly yourself (PHP, wget, curl, etc).